# How to release COM handle in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-installer, com-interop

I am using the following code under ASP.NET 4.0 framework to obtain the version of MSI file from a web app:

```
string strVersion = "";

try
{
    Type InstallerType;
    WindowsInstaller.Installer installer;

    InstallerType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
    installer = (WindowsInstaller.Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(InstallerType);

    WindowsInstaller.Database db = installer.OpenDatabase(strMSIFilePath, 0);

    WindowsInstaller.View dv = db.OpenView("SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property`='ProductVersion'");

    WindowsInstaller.Record record = null;

    dv.Execute(record);

    record = dv.Fetch();

    strVersion = record.get_StringData(1).ToString();

    dv.Close();
    //db.Commit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(dv);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(db);
}
catch
{
    //Failed
    strVersion = "";
}
```

It works fine except that when the code finishes running it holds an internal MSI file handle so when I try to move or rename the MSI file I get the error that the file is still in use. This continues until I actually navigate away from the ASPX page that calls the method above.

My question is, I obviously didn't close some handle or object in the code above. But what could that be?

PS. I'm testing it in a development IDE from VS2010.

**EDIT:** Edited the code like it should be after Adriano's suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Do any of the WindowsInstaller related classes implement IDisposable? If so you should place them in using blocks.

Comment: I honestly don't know much about WindowsInstaller. I tried using "using" and it didn't go thru. So I guess, not...

Comment: Windows Installer has both a Win32 API and an Automation Interface (COM).  From a .NET perspective the Win32 API is far cleaner to P/Invoke then the COM.  Additionally there already exists a rich set of classes to encapsulate all of this for you.  See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The COM object has not been released (it should be auto-released when it goes out of scope but in .NET this doesn't work really well). Because it does not implement the `IDisposable` interface you can't call its `Dispose()` method and you can't use it inside an `using` statement. You have to explicitly call [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). For example:

```
try
{
    // Your stuffs
}
finally
{
    dv.Close();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(dv);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(db);
}
```

Moreover note that you do not really need a call to the `Commit()` method because you didn't make any change but just a query.

Comment: Awesome! You just saved me a ton of time!!! Thanks a lot dude! Please also add this line to your answer: System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(dv); Calling it besides what you posted solves the issue. And the reason I was calling Commit() is because of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368254(v=vs.85).aspx#methods

Comment: I'd add that this ought to be in a `finally` block.  Thus it will always release the COM object even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: A better interop makes this easier.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, you should be using Windows Installer XML (WiX)  Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).  It's an FOSS project from Microsoft that can be found on CodePlex.   It has MSI interop libraries with classes that are very similar to the COM classes but implement IDisosable and use P/Invoke instead of COM behind the scenes.  There is even support for Linq to MSI if you want.  And the full source code is available.

DTF is the gold standard for MSI interop in a .NET world.  Here are two examples:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string DATABASE_PATH = @"C:\FOO..MSI";
        const string SQL_SELECT_PRODUCTVERSION = "SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property`='ProductVersion'";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Database database = new Database(DATABASE_PATH, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(database.ExecuteScalar(SQL_SELECT_PRODUCTVERSION).ToString());
            }
            using (QDatabase database = new QDatabase(DATABASE_PATH, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
            {
                var results = from property in database.Properties where property.Property == "ProductVersion" select property.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(results.AsEnumerable<string>().First());                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pointless to reinvent the wheel with an inferior solution.  Microsoft provided a proper library for encapsulating the Windows Installer API.

Answer (score -2):

try to `Dispose` the  Objects.

```
dv.Dispose();
db.Dispose();
```

Comment: These methods do not exist in dv and db.

Comment: Yes Actually I thought that, may be they implement IDisposable interface,but they donot ...so you cannot use Dispose method.  Adriano is right ..you need to use Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(db) to release COM references.